# Cannot subscript a value of type [uiButton] with an index of type 'UIButton' (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have an array of UIButton `radioController.buttonsArray = [ button1, button2, button3 ]` and would like to set the default to the selected button by passing the selected button to a function `radioController.defaultButton = radioController.buttonsArray[selectedButton]`

I want to use a string (originally was an integer, but the position in the array kept changing with the design), so above this, I tried:

```
var selectedButton: UIButton = button1
switch currentSelection {
    case "selection 1" : selectedButton = button1
    case "selection 2" : selectedButton = button2
    case "selection 3" : selectedButton = button3
    default: 
        break
}
```

I first get the error message: Value of optional type '[UIButton]?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'subscript' of wrapped base typ '[UIButton]'

but after "fixing" it ((with either ? or !) I get the message:
Cannot subscript a value of type [uiButton] with an index of type 'UIButton'

How do I declare selectedButton to do this?  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

You can only subscript arrays with `Int`s. If you want to find the index of a specific element in an array, you should use the `firstIndex(of:)` function on the array.

However, for your particular needs it seems there's no reason to access the array at all, since you already have access to the element you need.

You can just do `radioController.defaultButton = selectedButton`.

Comment: Thank you!  Sometimes I miss the forest for the trees.